# Write a String init in swift

Tags: init, swift5

In my code, an array of `[Int]` of size 3 has a special meaning. I want to get its string representation.

The most idiomatic in swift seems to me to be writing a new String initializer.

Something like this :

```
extension String {
    public init(point: [Int]) {
        assert(condition: point.count == 3)
        let r = "x=\(point[0]) y=\(point[1]) z=(point[2])"
        self.init(stringLiteral: r) // what should I write here ?? This feels clumsy ?
    }
```

What should go at the end of this `init` ? I can't assign to `self`, and there's no other obvious init that I should call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is a backslash missing in the String Interpolation line.

Just call `self.init` with `r` as parameter. Technically it's a *convenience initializer*.

```
extension String {
    public init(point: [Int]) {
        assert(point.count == 3)
        let r = "x=\(point[0]) y=\(point[1]) z=\(point[2])"
        self.init(r)
    }
}
```